# I2C dma circular mode with HAL stm32

Tags: stm32, i2c, dma, hal

I have already configured the DMA, I2C and the MPU9250. Now I want to read the output registers with the DMA in Circular mode. Is there a way to do that?

```c
HAL_I2C_Mem_Read_DMA(&hi2c1, I2C_SLV_ADDR << 1, ACCEL_XOUT_H_ADDR, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, mpu9250_rawdata, 14);
```

When I use this function it only executes once but I want to use this function basically in circular mode.

```
hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.Mode = DMA_CIRCULAR;
```

in the function **HAL_I2C_MspInit()** the DMA is configured with circular mode but it doesnt get executed then using **HAL_I2C_Mem_Read_DMA()**.

Is there a way to use the circular mode with the same function as **HAL_I2C_Mem_Read_DMA()**?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible (or even makes sense) with the I2C peripheral. SPI, ADC, DAC etc it should be possible. I've never seen it done with I2C. I2C has all kinds of packet framing, addresses, start and stop bits, ACKs etc. I don't know how the peripheral could do all that continuously in the way you hope.

Comment: @pmacfarlane how do I do it with SPI? I mean I have already configured it and what function do I have to call to start the SPI DMA circular reading of the data of the MPU9250?

Comment: I don't believe this device uses SPI. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Circular buffer DMA mode is probably not the solution to it.